# Getting Token and User Info iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on web view login form and I have requested the URL in web view and on success login I got an authorization code. Now to get token I am trying to use the code but seems like its status code 400.

How can I get the access token? Hopefully, the method should be right; I don't know where it's going wrong.

```
super.viewDidLoad()      
        let url = URL(string: "https://***/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=\(REDIRECT_URI)&client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

    }
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString{
            print("url = \(url)")

            let queryItems = URLComponents(string: url)?.queryItems
            authCode = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first
            sessionState = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "session_state"}).first

            print("CODE VALUE IS",authCode?.value as Any)
            print("SESSION STATE VALUE IS",sessionState?.value as Any)


           let headers = ["content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
            let postData = NSMutableData(data: "grant_type=\(GRANT_TYPE)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            postData.append("&client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            postData.append("&client_secret=\(CLIENT_SECRET)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            postData.append("&code=\(String(describing: authCode?.value))".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            postData.append("&redirect_ui=\(REDIRECT_URI)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: TOKEN_URL)! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            print("POSTDATA",postData.debugDescription)


           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData as Data

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error as Any)
                } else {
                    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

                    print("Response is",httpResponse as Any)
                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()
        }

}
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
Response is Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000230a60> { URL: https://account.eziemall.com/oauth2/token } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
        "Content-Length" =     (
            82
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "application/json"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Fri, 31 May 2019 11:03:42 GMT"
        );
        Server =     (
            "nginx/1.13.5"
        );
        "Set-Cookie" =     (
            "AWSALB=1Kah/jnLt4LFWcdh26U0DF9Jmf3IjVmSpKleCr9tNyq28wjoRANlQ6DSWcYGtMnWRJfBCQ0N7cMOpganMOaYVNzmoqp7vDyONPA1nwnYVdD9vJctwDAt7MB96xlf; Expires=Fri, 07 Jun 2019 11:03:42 GMT; Path=/"
        );
        "x-content-type-options" =     (
            nosniff
        );
        "x-xss-protection" =     (
            "1; mode=block"
        );
    } })
```

Comment: Could it be a typo `&redirect_ui` vs. `&redirect_uri`? By the way, don't use `NSMutable...` classes in Swift. There is `Data` and `URLRequest` which is mutable as `var`iable. And there is `URL`

Comment: @vadian Thanks, but it's still the same status.

Comment: you have some more header missing i think so ... check them carefully

Comment: Does `authCode?.value` return the expected result? An created string from an optional adds literal `"Optional(` even with the (anyway misused and redundant) `String(describing` initializer.

Comment: Yes i get response with auth code and session state after success login and i pass it here.

Comment: In WKWebView, didFinish navigation i pass  if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString{
            print("url = \(url)")
            
            
            let queryItems = URLComponents(string: url)?.queryItems
            authCode = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first
            sessionState = queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "session_state"}).first
            
            print("CODE VALUE IS",authCode?.value as Any)
            print("SESSION STATE VALUE IS",sessionState?.value as Any)

Comment: Unformatted code in comments is very hard to read. Please edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: @vadian I have edited it , please check.

Comment: Unrelated, but use `URLRequest` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest`. It would also avoid you the "as URLRequest". In fact, avoir NSStuff when possible (if Stuff is available) in Swift 3+: NSMutableData, etc.

Comment: And what does `print("CODE VALUE IS",authCode?.value as Any)` display?

Comment: @vadian url = http://xyz/auth?code=e3443f75-c5d0-37db-a6f4-1eb9406b951e&session_state=06157dcc5a8005c8638710f1944e198b90d56a96be24fa01140fa625996728b2.LovtOy1Psp87xaj9FPoujw
CODE VALUE IS Optional("e3443f75-c5d0-37db-a6f4-1eb9406b951e")
SESSION STATE VALUE IS Optional("06157dcc5a8005c8638710f1944e198b90d56a96be24fa01140fa625996728b2.LovtOy1Psp87xaj9FPoujw")

Comment: It prints auth code and session state (not hardcode) from the url response of success login

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected. The literal `"Optional(` breaks the code. You are sending `"Optional(\"e3...`. Unwrap the optional

Comment: @vadian so what should i do here?  print("CODE VALUE IS",authCode!) Force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning ? and when i did it gives Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. So you mean i am not getting the auth code right ?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Comment: How should i edit the code with right process to get auth code and token id if am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the reason of the error is the optional `authCode?.value` which adds a literal `"Optional(` in String Interpolation.

Unwrap the optional in the first `if let` line.

This is an improved version getting rid of the ugly *objective-c-ish* `NSMutable...` classes

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString, let authCodeValue = authCode?.value {
        let headers = ["content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        var postString = "grant_type=\(GRANT_TYPE)"
        postString += "&client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)"
        postString += "&client_secret=\(CLIENT_SECRET)"
        postString += "&code=\(authCodeValue)"
        postString += "&redirect_uri=\(REDIRECT_URI)"

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: TOKEN_URL)!)
        request.cachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = Data(postString.utf8)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("Response is", httpResponse)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the requirements of the API.

Comment: For that i have to do JSONSerialization to get the object value and i got it. This optional string as taken me so deep :D Thank you so much for your help and time. Really appreciated (y)